# Rejected tx with old nonce on Parity

Tags: ethereum, parity-io

I had observed that the transaction send to the Parity node didn't processed,
and the error messsage "Rejected tx with old nonce" was shown.
The nonce value of the sendTransaction call was calculated so that it would become
the next nonce value. The message was not applicable to the situation.

There are three validator nodes in our Parity environment.
The version of Parity is 2.5.13, and it runs on Ubuntu Server 18.04.

The reproducibility of the phenomeon is not good, and it tends to be resolved with the passage of time.

Is there something that is considered to be the cause of the phenomeon？
When it will occur again, how will I survey the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Only you with the private key can generate valid transactions. So you need to figure out why your code posts transactions with the same nonce to the Parity /  mempool.

- Check for duplicate transactions
- Check for nonce reuse

Comment: Thank you. When the same problem will occur, I will check if I do not use the same nonce value (although nonce value is calculated so as not to reuse old nonce value).